# How to read new data from file after the file has been added to

Tags: linux

Running on RHEL 7

I want to be able to only read in new data from log files and add to a database.

Using python-evtx I can read the windows log data and pipe to a script, that then writes to mysql, also same thing with my apache logs.

This issue is my script is scanning the whole file, and writing all the data over again to the DB

Is there anyway in Linux (RHEL) I can have the script read only the "new" data from the last time it was run?

ie

script runs at 1:10

```
cat \logfile.txt
a
b
c
d
```

script runs at 1:20

```
cat \logfile.txt
g
h
j
k
a
b
c
d
```

How can I just capture g,h,j,k

Comment: You could keep track of the file size when you check it and then use `tail -c CURRENTFILESIZE-LASTFILESIZE` (replace LASTFILESIZE with however you choose to save the last file size - environment variable, written to a file, etc.) to get data written since the last time you checked the file.  If you rotate logfile.txt, be sure to keep track of the inode # of the file so you can check to see if the file was rotated.

Comment: Or replace `tail` with `head` if your logfile really does have the most recent data first (which might be considered unusual for log files)